# How to iterate through table rows in Java?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to iterate through an sql table using JPA, example of use:
I have the table Person which contains 100 columns

```
id | gender | firstname | lastname |  address1 | address2 | number | ....+100
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-  |  ...   |   .....   |   ...    |   ....    |   ....   |   ..   |  ....
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-  |  ...   |   .....   |   ...    |   ....    |   ....   |   ..   |  ....
```

and in my Java program, I want to do the following (as an example):

- for each row
- get the firstname
- get the number
- do operation with firstname
- do operation with number

the problem is that I don't want to create an Entity class of Person because it contains 100 columns and it's quite cumbersome and I'm not interested with all of them.

Also, I don't want to retrieve the row in an Object[] type, because suppose that I want to extract 40 columns out of 100, it will be confusing to manipulate such a type.

I'm using spring data JPA and not JDBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an entity class with only the columns you're interrested in.

And then, with Spring data, you will get a collection of Person class which you can iterate through the way you like.

Comment: ok suppose i created a customPerson class with firstname and number as attributes, then in the JpaRepository interface, how can i retreieve the data ? @Query(select firstname , number from person) List<customPerson> getcustomperson(); ?

Comment: If you use Spring data, you don't even have to use a Query annotation if your request is a simple one.
In your case, it should look like this (where your id is a Long type):
 @Repository("personRepository")
 public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomPerson, Long> {

  List<CustomPerson> findAll();

 }

Comment: Spring data creates the query based on the method name

Comment: yes ok , but if i do this : List<CustomPerson> findAll();  , how can he recognize the "firstname" and "number" column among the other ? by checking the similarity between the column name and the attributes ? also , i fi want a custom query , the way i wrote it above is a valid one , isn't it ?

Comment: the @Column annotation allows you to create a match between your entity and the columns.

Comment: For a custom query, this is like this : @Query("select p from CustomPerson p") and all attributes of the CustomPerson Entity will be provided. If you want a parameter, il will be like @Query("select p from CustomPerson p where p.firstname=:fisrtName") where you have a String parameter called firstName in your method.

Comment: are your sure that this solution you provided me  in 5th comment works ?

Comment: The @Column annotation ? 100% sure, I use it every day. It's not mandatory. If your field matches your attribute name, you don't have to use it. But I find it clearer to use it anyway. What is you issue ?

Comment: even if all my attributes(with @Column) are matching only a few columns among all others in the table ? beacause here is my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549813/why-the-entity-cant-map-the-columns-table

Comment: Do you have any error message when you launch your app ? If not, the mapping is OK. Otherwise, it would tell you. If your SQL is not shown in your logs, modify your logger configuration so it shows you. Then, run it in your SQL client to check if the return is OK

Comment: yes i had an error in maven clean and install , so now since i resolved it , i'll will retry , and i will let you know if i will encounter the same issue

Comment: i still have the same output (size = 0) , but  i think that the problem is because i have two mysql databases , therefore the entity choose the wrong database to map its columns. but i'm not sure

Comment: Yeah, to make sure of it, you can add a line in the empty database et see if your size is now 1.

Comment: yes you were right , in fact , i added a line in the empty newly database , and the size is now = 1 , it means that the program fetch the wrong database (it creates a Person table in the seconddatabase and maps with it instead of mapping with the existing Person Table in the first database) , how can i change the database currently mapped with my Person Entity?

Comment: yess it worked , i just added @table(catalog = "databasename" , name = "Person") ! thank you a lot !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220343/discussion-between-benjamind-and-recoba78).