# why the entity can't map the columns table?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity

i have a mysql table "countries" as follow

```
| id | name | name2 | code | area | currency | language | population |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| .. | ..   |   ... |   ...|  ....|  ...     |   ...    |   ...      |
```

this entity "customCountry":

```
@Entity
@Table(name="countries")
public class customCountry {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id",table ="countries")
     private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code",table ="countries")
     private Long code;

    @Column(name = "language",table ="countries")
     private String language;

   //constructors + getters/setters
}
```

i have this repository :

```
@Repository
public interface customCountryRepository extends JpaRepository<customCountry,Long>{

    
    List<customCountry> findAll();
}
```

and this service class :

```
@Service
@ComponentScan(basePackages="repository")
public class countriesService {

    @Autowired
    customCountryRepository customcountry_repo;
    
    public List<customCountry> loadcustomcountries()
    {
        List<customCountry> validcustomcountries = customcountry_repo.findAll();
        System.out.println("size: "+validcustomcountries.size());
        return validcustomcountries;
    }
}
```

the problem is that when i called this service method in my controller , i find out that the size = 0 , but i don't see why , i think that i well managed the mapping between attributes and columns though .
thank you

Comment: Do you have data-rows in your table? Or is it empty..?

Comment: yes ! i have data rows in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove  **`List<customCountry> findAll();`** from repository class.

As you had already extended **`JpaRepository<customCountry,Long>`**, it's have this method.

As you are providing that method in repository but not implementation of it.
That is causing an issue.

Just try by removing it.